# How to check if a string is contained on an NSArray entry?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Let's guess I have an NSArray which looks like:

```
(
    "zad0xsis|mac",
    "+zad0xsis",
    @someone,
    %another-one",
    ~admin,
)
```

How can I check if a NSString is equal to some on the array (but always removing the +, @, ~, % symbols in front)? I though about using a `for` loop, but not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used

```
for(int i=0; i<[self.userArray count]; i++) {
       NSString *user = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:i];
       NSLog(@"%@", user);
}
```

Which got me the index I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

The other methods cited are very good.  Another option is to utilize NSArray's block based enumeration methods.  The block based methods allow you to take advantage of concurrency on the platform you are developing for and are the way of the future.  The method I was thinking of is as follows:

- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts passingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate

so for you situation you could use the following:

```
NSUInteger theIndex=NSNotFound;
theIndex=[theArray indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger, idx, BOOL *stop){
     if ([obj rangeOfString: aString]!=NSNotFound]){
         *stop=YES;
         return YES;
     }
     return NO;
}];
```

solution also discussed here:  [How to check if an NSString contains one of the NSStrings in an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702359/how-to-check-if-an-nsstring-contains-one-of-the-nsstrings-in-an-nsarray)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rangeOfString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) which is part of the [`NSString Class`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

```
BOOL exists = NO;
for (NSString *what in myArray)
{
    if ([someSearchString rangeOfString:what].location != NSNotFound) {
        exists = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be any way of knowing the index of the found result?